# Error when NSSortDesctiptor to sort by plist number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using a `NSSortDescriptor` to sort my tableView but this line is making trouble:

```
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Rate" ascending:NO];
}
```

"Rate" is a Number string in a plist (array with dictionaries).

If dictionary is unrated, default value is "0" and if it is rated, value is "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" or "6". Why can't I sort by these values, and how to do so?

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c382c0'

EDIT:

The problem is that I am rating the dictionary with a string instead of Number:

```
[mutDict setValue:@"0" forKey:@"Rate"];
```

How to set a number for Rate instead of string?

Comment: Are you sure it's the right line? The complaint is about the `length` selector, while your descriptor asks for a `Rate`.

Comment: No I'm sorry, the problem is that when I rate the dictionary, the rate is written as a string instead of number! Will update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set a number for Rate instead of string?

You can use `NSNumber` instead of a string literal:

```
[mutDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"Rate"];
//          The actual rate goes here ----^
```

Other class methods for `NSNumber` include `numberWithLong`, `numberWithDouble`, and `NumberWithFloat`.

Comment: It's telling me that numberWithInt is udeclared identitfier